# awk - match positive whole numbers and floating point numbers only

Tags: bash, awk

I have an input file in .csv format which contains entries of tax invoices separated by pipe.

for example:

```
Header--TIN | NAME | INV NO | DATE | NET | TAX | OTHERS | TOTAL
Record1-29001234768 | A S Spares | AB012 | 23/07/2016 | 5600.25 | 200.70 | 10.05 | 5811.00
Record2-29450956221 | HONDA Spare Parts | HOSS0987 |29/09/2016 | 70000 | 2200 | 0 | 72200
```

The record's NET value, TAX Value, OTHER Charges and TOTAL value column may contain positive whole numbers or positive floating point numbers with 2-4 places after the decimal point.

Now my requirement is to check whether the columns meets the specified constraints by checking with appropriate **'Regular Expression using awk'**.
I need to match these 4 columns with regular expression such that if I encounter any numeric value other than positive whole number or positive floating point number , I need to print an error message to the user.

I've tried the following , but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if(!($5 ~ /[0-9]+/) || !($5 ~ /[0-9]+[.][0-9]+/) || ($5<=0))
    { printf("NET VALUE (Violates constraints)" }
```

Can anyone give the proper working regular expression or any implementation using built-in-function to meet my requirements?

Comment: Don't forget that the `~` operator will return true if the regex occurs __anywhere__ in the field being tested. E.g.: `awk 'BEGIN { if ("abc8xyz" ~ /[0-9]+/) print "is this a hint?" }'`

Comment: There are no commas in your posted input file so that is, obviously, not CSV. [edit] your question to either show us the real CSV input file, or remove the talk about CSV if that's your real input format.

Comment: @Ed Morton - I've used sed command to replace all commas by pipes for better understanding. It is of course a .csv file which is obtained by converting an .ods file using libreoffice, but replaced commas with pipes.

Comment: I understand the temptation to do that but don't. If you provide something we can test against then we will test against it and if you provide something that isn't your real input, no matter how much prettier or clearer you might think it looks, it makes it harder for us to create test input from (so most of us won't bother) and can result in you getting a solution to a problem you don't actually have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your validation should be:

```
$5 ~ /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2,4})?$/
```

If it matches that, then it's valid (either a positive whole number, or a number followed by `.` and between 2 and 4 other numbers).

The anchors to the start and end of the field are important!

As rightly pointed out in the comments, if you want to accept numbers with no digits before the decimal point, then you will have to go for a more complex regular expression.

Comment: Oh..Sorry ... I do not have any space between pipelines and values in the records.

Comment: @Shreyas note that there was a typo in my pattern (an extra parenthesis) which I have edited to remove.

Comment: @TomFenech: I tried this `echo "345.23" | awk '{ if($0 ~ /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2,4})?$/) print "good" }'` and it did not work.. It worked for numbers without decimal points

Comment: @TomFrench - The regular expression provided in the answer is absolutely working like a charm for all cases of inputs provided.

Comment: @TomFenech: For me it is no output.. My bash version is `4.1.2` and awk version is `3.1.7` if that is of any help.

Comment: @Fazlin you have a prehistoric version of gawk so add `--re-interval` up front to enable RE intervals and then get a newer version of gawk ASAP!

Comment: `.10` is a positive floating point number that will be rejected by that regexp.